# How to Format a UILabel for a recipe list containing multi line text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am loading a recipe from a database which contains an array of recipe ingredients, comprised of a quantity, unit of measure (cup, tbsp, tsp), and a description (Egg, Milk). I want to display the recipe in a nice list format:

> 1   Cup  Wheat Flour
>
> 1/2 Cup  Strawberries
>
> 1   Cup  Milk
>
> 1   oz   Here is an ingredient with a very long description 
>             And needs to be put on 2 lines to fit on iPhone screen
>
> 1 oz Last list item

I am wondering how to get a `UIlabel` to properly display the text like above so that an ingredient description that needs to be broken up into multiple lines can have a hanging indent so that it's not just at the beginning of the line which looks messy. I have tried 3 separate labels (one for quantities, one for units, one for description) however i cannot figure out how to make sure an ingredients attributes (unit, description, quantity) always start on the same line.

Here is what a bad format would look like:

> 1 List item that is very long blah blah blah blahblah blahblah
>   blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blahblah blah
>   and doesn't have hanging indent
>
> 2 List item
>
> 3 List item

Comment: Look into attributed text and paragraph formatting.

Comment: And consider using a text view instead of a label.

Comment: Use a `UITextView` rather than a `UILabel`.

Comment: there are a lot of different ways to archive this. stackoverflow is not a place to order tutorials for a specific problem. try to find your way and if you have sourcecode that does not work as you except post that and ask for help.